How can I check if a generated radio button is checked in PyQt5?
I'm creating a class roster with PyQt5.
I generated several radio buttons along with each student entry. I want to be able to check the radio button and click another button to delete the entry. I am having trouble identifying which radio button is clicked because they have no unique name attached. Any suggestions? TIA.
for student in all_students:
    name_info= f'{student[0]}, {student[1]} ({str(student[2])})'
    radioButton = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self)
    radioButton.setText(name_info)
    radioButton.setFont(QtGui.QFont('Courier', 15))
    form_layout.addRow(radioButton)

form_layout.addRow(QtWidgets.QPushButton('Delete Student', clicked = lambda: delete_student(self)))

def delete_student(self):
    if radioButton.isChecked():
        print(radioButton.text())

FYI - if this code worked properly, it would just print radio button text (which is all I need right now), but I am getting nothing.
I also tried putting each generated radio button in a list and then iterate through them to check if they were checked, but that threw an error too.
Here are what the radio buttons look like in the app if that helps:

You can add the buttons to a QButtonGroup and use its checkedButton() method.

"that threw an error too." What error? Please show how you did that.

@dz1981-bit Note that your usage of self seems quite odd, as it's normally used for instance method, while you're just calling a function, leading me to thing that you're not using an actual class, but just "patching" code without really understanding how it works. Please take your time to do more proper research about basic OOP aspects and how classes/instances and their members/methods function.
